# d3d12: when adding a constant buffer, the Output structure changes

Tags: c++, directx, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, directx-12

light strip, this is related to float3 worldPos
For some reason it does not change along the x axis
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Wn1.jpg)

coloring a pixel depending on worldPos
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqNut.jpg)
worldPos depends on object coordinates and not on pixel coordinates

what the colors should look like based on worldPos
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msuwD.jpg)

vertex shader:

```
cbuffer rot : register(b0)
{
    matrix modelViewProj;
    matrix model;
};

struct Output
{
    float3 worldPos : Position;
    float3 n : Normal;
    float4 pos : SV_Position;
    float2 tc : Texcoord;
};

Output main(float3 pos : Position, float3 n : Normal, float2 tc : Texcoord)
{
    Output vertexOut;

    vertexOut.worldPos = (float3)mul(float4(pos, 1.0f), model);
    vertexOut.pos = mul(float4(pos, 1.0f), modelViewProj);
    vertexOut.n = mul(n, (float3x3) model);
    vertexOut.tc = tc;
    
    return vertexOut;
}
```

pixel shader:

```
struct ObjectCBuf
{
    float3 materialColor;
};

cbuffer LightCBuf : register(b1)
{
    float3 lightPos;
    float3 ambient;
    float3 diffuseColor;
    float diffuseIntensity;
    float attConst;
    float attLin;
    float attQuad;
    ObjectCBuf object;
};

float4 main(float3 worldPos : Position, float3 n : Normal, float4 pos : SV_Position) : SV_TARGET
{
    const float3 vToL = lightPos - worldPos;
    const float distToL = length(vToL);
    const float3 dirToL = vToL / distToL;
    // diffuse attenuation
    const float att = 1.0f / (attConst + attLin * distToL + attQuad * (distToL * distToL));
    // diffuse intensity
    const float3 diffuse = diffuseColor * diffuseIntensity * att * max(0.0f, dot(dirToL, n));
    // final color
    //return float4(object.materialColor, 1.0);
    return float4(saturate((diffuse + ambient) * object.materialColor), 1.0f);
}
```

when I don't add a constant buffer in c++ code then worldPos behaves fine

Answer (score 0):

There's a memory alignment issue. For `float2` to `float4` vectors for constant buffers, you need to make sure they are aligned to `float4` boundaries, or it gets "torn up". The same goes for D3D11. (But additionally, for D3D12, a constant buffer needs to have a total size aligned to 256 bytes, that's 64 `float`s, or 16 `float4`s)

In your case, you have `float3 lightPos` and `float3 ambient` right next to each other, this is how they will be placed in memory:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lightPos.x | lightPos.y | lightPos.z | ambient.x |
| ambient.y | ambient.z | diffuseColor.x | diffuseColor.y |

do you see the issue here? `float3 ambient` (as well as `float3 diffuseColor`) have their elements "on different rows", `float*` vectors must be read as a whole in hlsl, and hlsl can only read "on the same row" for each variable. Value `ambient.x` is (probably) read correctly, but value `ambient.y` and `ambient.z` is lost, and they will probably end up being `0.0f`. I say "probably" because it's undefined behavior, there's no guarantee that this is what will end up happening on every hardware.

This is how I would change the code:

```
cbuffer LightCBuf : register(b1)
{
    // row 0
    float3 lightPos;
    float diffuseIntensity;

    // row 1
    float3 ambient;
    float attConst;

    // row 2
    float3 diffuseColor;
    float attLin;

    // row 3
    float attQuad;
    ObjectCBuf object;
};
```

notice from the code above, that I've placed a float alongside each float3, filling an entire 4 floats' length of memory before moving on to the next element, so that each float3 will end up being "on the same row".